# Ractive: How to access a variable integer index keypath of an array in a Ractive view

Tags: ractivejs

I have a 'collection' (extended ractive object) that has a keypath of 'collection' in the data key of the object which is an array of records.

The view loops the collection with `{{#each collection:i}}` and a href is generated for the name of each record.

When the user clicks a link on a collection item, an event is triggered which sets a 'selectedIndex' property `obj.set('selectedIndex',i)`

In my view then, how then do I access the record in collection at this index?

`<input type="text" name="title" value="{{abc}}" placeholder="Name">`

Where 'abc' is something like 'collection[selectedIndex].prop'

Of course its fine if selectedIndex is not variable, I could use `collection.1.prop` or `collection[1].prop` ... but I've tried every possible combination and hunted through the docs but I can't see how to do this ... surely it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much nailed it:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value="{{collection[selectedIndex].prop}}" placeholder="Name">
```

Looks like you need to guard against the non-existent value (or set a default), see http://jsfiddle.net/m199umtv/